# case expression in where clause to include multiple values

Tags: t-sql

I have multiple clients with a single identifying code and 2 clients with multiple identifiers. I'm trying to find a good way to use the client code as a parameter for a stored procedure for both a single and multiple codes in the where clause.

I currently have a variable that takes the parameter entered and converts it into a single character (the client code) but using the variable with "in" does not work. I've also tried to format the client codes as a case expression in the where clause but haven't been able to figure out the formatting for it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[client_tonnage] @input varchar(100)
as

select input = 
   case
       when @input = 'client1' then 'C1'
       when @input = 'client2' then '''C2'', ''C3'', ''C4'''

if object_id('tempdb..#temp_table') is not null drop table #temp_table

insert into #temp_table (date_time, clientid, ACTUAL_WEIGHT) 
from Log
where clientid in (@input)

select * from #temp_table
```

I'd like to be able to include the clients with multiple client codes but the format above does not work. Any work-arounds would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is trying to hold multiple values in a variable that's not a table variable. Use a table variable and use it with a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hold multiple values, use a table variable:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[client_tonnage] @input varchar(100)
as
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ClientIDs TABLE (ClientID VARCHAR(10))

    IF @input = 'client1'
        INSERT INTO @ClientIDs (ClientID) VALUES ('C1')
    ELSE IF @input = 'client2'
        INSERT INTO @ClientIDs (ClientID) VALUES ('C2'),('C3'),('C4')

    if object_id('tempdb..#temp_table') is not null 
        drop table #temp_table

    insert into #temp_table (date_time, clientid, ACTUAL_WEIGHT) 
    SELECT
        -- The proper columns
    from 
        Log AS L
        INNER JOIN @ClientIDs AS C ON L.clientid = C.ClientID

    select * from #temp_table

END
```

Although you are hard-coding the "mappings" between the input and the client IDs. A better way would be to store this relationship in a physical table:

```
CREATE TABLE ClientMappings (
    ClientID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    ClientCode VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO ClientMappings (
    ClientID,
    ClientCode)
VALUES
    ('C1', 'client1'),
    ('C2', 'client2'),
    ('C3', 'client2'),
    ('C4', 'client2')
```

So you solve this with a simple join:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[client_tonnage] @input varchar(100)
as
BEGIN

    if object_id('tempdb..#temp_table') is not null 
        drop table #temp_table      

    insert into #temp_table (date_time, clientid, ACTUAL_WEIGHT) 
    SELECT
        -- The proper columns
    from 
        Log AS L
        INNER JOIN ClientMappings AS C ON L.clientid = C.ClientID
    WHERE
        C.clientcode = @input

    select * from #temp_table

END
```

Also if your SP is *just* selecting this data, you don't need the temporary table.

Comment: This was perfectly explained. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
select input =
```

That is not the same as the parameter, as you are missing the `@` symbol.

You want:

```
select @input = 
   case
       when @input = 'client1' then 'C1'
       when @input = 'client2' then '''C2'', ''C3'', ''C4'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression by putting all of the logic inside the `case`. Note that a `case` expression returns a single value which you must then do something with, e.g. compare it to one.

```
insert into #temp_table (date_time, clientid, ACTUAL_WEIGHT) 
  from Log
  where case
    when @input = 'client1' and clientid = 'C1' then 1
    when @input = 'client2' and clientid in ( 'C2', 'C3', 'C4' ) then 1
    else 0 end = 1;
```

This is likely to suffer from [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/).